# Spring AOP advice not getting executed

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I'm trying to get advice executed, and it isn't working. I am trying to do it without an application context.

This is my Rest Controller:

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import aspect.exception.GreetingsNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
     public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

Aspect class:

```
    @Aspect
//@ComponentScan
public class AfterThrowingException implements ThrowsAdvice {

    // Obtain a suitable logger.
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AfterThrowingException.class);

      @Before("execution(hello.GreetingController.greeting()")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint){
    System.out.println("Inside AfterThrowingException.logBefore()");
}
```

Configuration class:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public AfterThrowingException afterThrowingException() {
        return new AfterThrowingException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The format of [execution pointcut is](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html):

   ```
     execution(modifiers-pattern? ret-type-pattern declaring-type-pattern?name-pattern(param-pattern)
           throws-pattern?)
   ```
2. Your controller method takes parameters, but it is not in the definition

Try:

```
 @Before("* execution(hello.GreetingController.greeting(..)")
```

3. You need to proceed after completing of @Before advice

   ```
     jointPoint.proceed();
   ```
4. Your names are out of sync